# Stop displaying tmux information about smaller client

Tags: tmux

When we connect to the tmux session, it shows information at bottom right something like this : (size 80*24 from a smaller client) and fills area with dots and boundary with green color. How we can disable it ? Don't want to show any such information.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: No. never..if anyone find it, please do share.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had two "ghost" tmux clients connected.  Perhaps old VSCode sessions got stuck serverside, dunno.  But I just had to `tmux detach` twice to fix the problem:

```
$ tmux list-clients
/dev/pts/29: 0 [129x20 xterm-256color] (utf8) 
/dev/pts/55: 0 [132x27 xterm-256color] (utf8) 
$ tmux detach
$ tmux list-clients
/dev/pts/29: 0 [129x20 xterm-256color] (utf8) 
$ tmux detach
$ tmux list-clients
$ tmux a
```